# How can I get the struct field of a map elem in Go's html/template?

Tags: templates, go

I have a Struct `Task`:

```
type Task struct {
   cmd string
   args []string
   desc string
}
```

And I init a map which take the above `Task` struct as a value and a `string` as a key(the task name)

```
var taskMap = map[string]Task{
    "find": Task{
        cmd: "find",
        args: []string{"/tmp/"},
        desc: "find files in /tmp dir",
    },
    "grep": Task{
        cmd: "grep",
        args:[]string{"foo","/tmp/*", "-R"},
        desc: "grep files match having foo",
    },
}
```

and I want to parse a html page using `html/template` just using the above `taskMap`.

```
func listHandle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.tmpl")
    t.Execute(w, taskMap)
}
```

Here is the `index.tmpl`:

```
<html>
{{range $key, $value := .}}
   <li>Task Name:        {{$key}}</li>
   <li>Task Value:       {{$value}}</li>
   <li>Task description: {{$value.desc}}</li>
{{end}}
</html>
```

I can get the `$key` and `value` printed successfully, but When It comes to the field of `Task` using `{{$value.desc}}` it wont work.

How can I get the `desc` of each `task` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: you can try/check out your working modified code in the [**Go Playground**](http://play.golang.org/p/mKTVCHB3Lv).

---

If you want the `template` package to be able to access the fields, you have to export the fields. You can export a field by starting it with an uppercase letter:

```
type Task struct {
   cmd string
   args []string
   Desc string
}
```

Note that I only changed `Desc` here, you have to uppercase any other fields you want to refer to in the template.

After this exporting, change all references to uppercase `Desc` of course:

```
var taskMap = map[string]Task{
    "find": Task{
        cmd: "find",
        args: []string{"/tmp/"},
        Desc: "find files in /tmp dir",
    },
    "grep": Task{
        cmd: "grep",
        args:[]string{"foo","/tmp/*", "-R"},
        Desc: "grep files match having foo",
    },
}
```

And also in the template:

```
<html>
{{range $key, $value := .}}
   <li>Task Name:        {{$key}}</li>
   <li>Task Value:       {{$value}}</li>
   <li>Task description: {{$value.Desc}}</li>
{{end}}
</html>
```

Output:

```
<html>

<li>Task Name:        find</li>
<li>Task Value:       {find [/tmp/] find files in /tmp dir}</li>
<li>Task description: find files in /tmp dir</li>

<li>Task Name:        grep</li>
<li>Task Value:       {grep [foo /tmp/* -R] grep files match having foo}</li>
<li>Task description: grep files match having foo</li>

</html>
```

Comment: So that explains it.　@icza I happened to realize that you have answered at least two of my questions now. Wish I could offer you a drink some day :-) thank you again. really helpful.

Comment: @armnotstrong Actually I've answered already 4 of your questions.

Comment: It's really nice of you